Solution to Cauchy multiplicative equation.
I was watching this video by Tom Crawford, where this problem came up:
$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$
$f'(0)=3$
$f(x)=\space?$
My first thought was to use the product rule on the function.
$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$
$f'(0)=3$
$f'(x+y)=f'(x)f(y)+f(x)f'(y)$
$f'(0+0)=f'(0)f(0) + f(0)f'(0)$
$f'(0)=3f(0)+3f(0)=6f(0)$
$3=6f(0)$
$f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$
It then followed to something I'm pretty sure was NOT the answer...
$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$
$f(0 + n)=\frac{1}{2}f(n)$
$\therefore f(x)=0, \forall \space x \space \epsilon \space \mathbb{R}$
The answer is meant to be $e^{3x}$, and I understand how they got that, but I don't understand why my method is incorrect? Any help is appreciated!
The link to his video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efXbABwhCtE

Your differentiation is wrong. Differentiate w.r.t. either $x$ or $y$ keeping the other variable fixed.

$f'(x+y)=f'(x)f(y)$ and $f'(x+y)=f(x)f'(y)$, but not their sum, so letting $y=0$ you get $f'(x)=f'(x)f(0)$ and $f'(x)=f(x)\times 3$  which give you $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=ke^{3x}$, and thus $k=1$ and $f(x)=e^{3x}$.

Thank you all so much!
